# Updating PHP in fedora Instance on AMAZON EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, fedora

I have a fedora Instance runnig in an Amazon EC2. The problem is, I have a php already installed, but I want to update (PS: Somebody already gave to me the instance with the php installed). When I try the command: yum update php an error message appears.

```
   Setting up Update Process
   Setting up repositories
   Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: updates-released
   Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: updates-released
```

I tried to uncomment the baseurl line in the yum repositorie files, but a new error appears.

```
Setting up Update Process
   Setting up repositories
    http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/core/updates/4/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (-2, 'Name or service not known')>
   Trying other mirror.
   Cannot open/read repomd.xml file for repository: updates-released
   failure: repodata/repomd.xml from updates-released: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from updates-released: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting sounds like it's a connection or DNS related issue -- see if you can ping 'download.fedora.redhat.com,' then see if you can use wget to attempt to get the file.

Also, your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory may contain a repository file with an invalid repository in it -- I'm not sure if they're still publishing updates for Fedora 4 (it was released around 2004ish).  Your best bet is to make sure that the version in /etc/fedora-release matches with the version in that repository configuration file.